# How to use results of one slick query in another with computation in between

Tags: scala, slick

I have a database table InventoryLotUsage which has columns id, inventoryLotId, and date.  I want to delete an InventoryLot, but before I can do that I need to update the InventoryLotUsage rows that have a foreign key inventoryLotId, based on date and some other conditions.
My question is how do I query for data using monadic joins, do some computations on it and use the result of those computations to run an update all in one transaction in Slick?

I was attempting to get a sequence of rows like this

```
for {
      il <- InventoryLot.filter(_.id === id)
      lotUsage <- InventoryLotUsage.filter(_.inventoryLotId === id).result
      groupedUsage = lotUsage.groupBy(_.date)
      ...
}
```

my IDE suggests that lotUsage will be a Seq[InventoryLotUsageRows], but when compiling I get a type error because of the .result.

```
type mismatch;
 found   : slick.dbio.DBIOAction[FacilityProductRepository.this.InventoryLot,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read with slick.dbio.Effect.Read with slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
 required: slick.lifted.Query[?,?,?]
      lotUsage <- InventoryLotUsage.filter(_.inventoryLotId === id).result
```

Without using .result its type is the InventoryLotUsage table.  How can I wrangle the query into something usable for computation?

Comment: I think you forgot the .result on the `il <-` line

Answer (score 1):

You need to compose [DBIOActions](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/dbio.html) to archive desired result. For example:

Load all data that you need

```
val loadStaffAction = (for {
   il <- InventoryLot.filter(_.id === id)
   lotUsage <- InventoryLotUsage.filter(_.inventoryLotId === id)
} yield (il, lotUsage)).result
```

Then you could use `map/flatMap` on `loadStaffAction` to create update statements based on computations. You can also use for-comprehensions here.

```
val updateAction = loadStaffAction.map { result =>
  // creating update statements based on some computations and conditions
  DBIO.seq(
    InventoryLotUsage.filter(_.id === inventory1.id).map(_.name).update("new value"),
    InventoryLotUsage.filter(_.id === inventory2.id).map(_.name).update("another value"),
  );
}
```

After this you can run all queries in one transaction

```
db.run(updateAction.transactionally)
```